# Wordpress: Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, referenceerror

This is the javascript I enqueue en wordpress but I have this error. "Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined ".

```
(function($) {
    function myfunction(bf) {
        if(bf.checked)
            var text1 = document.getElementById("shipping_first_name").value;
        else
            text1='';
        document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value = text1;
        };
})(jQuery);
```

Also I tried with this code too.

```
(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function myFunction(bf) {
            if(bf.checked)
                var text1 = document.getElementById("shipping_first_name").value;
            else
                text1='';

            document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value = text1;
            }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Enqueue:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/shipping.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        false,
        '1.0',
        true
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: A method define inside a clouser is only accessible from the clouser itself.

(function(){
  /***
  */
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method defined inside a closure is only accessible inside the closure itself.

```
            (function(){
                /* This is called closure
                 All code here is solely on clouser
                */
            }())
```

To access the method you can alter the closure as follows

```
            (function(){
                window.myfunction = function(bf){
                    /*...*/
                }
            }())
```

Comment: I dont really get it, what about the noconflict (})(jQuery);)

Comment: I guess you mean closure, not closour :)

Comment: @AdriánVázquez where is your noconflict, I can't see any noconflict use in your code.

Comment: Sorry forget that. Where I put the variable like myFunction(bf)?